# Saving plot in R

Tags: r, macos, graph

I  use macOS and ı saved my graph file as pdf, jpeg and gif. But ı have trouble in resizing them. in windows we can use metafile comment . 
is there any comment like windows in Mac ?

Comment: Save as svg or pdf, then manipulate in inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a graphic in `R` and save it as a PDF, you can use the arguments `width` and `height` to resize the graphics regions in inches. You can also use the `fonts` argument to change the font size in your plot:

```
pdf("testplot.pdf", width=12, height=9, fonts=12)
plot(1:10, rnorm(10, 0, 5))
dev.off()
```

For PNG, JPEG, TIFF or BMP, you can use the same logic, but note that the `width` and `height` are measured in pixels (`px`) instead of inches (`in`). You can change this manually. Note that you can just replace `png()` with `jpeg()`, `tiff()` or `bmp()` for the different formats. Also note that you'll have to specify the dpi (dots per inch) in `res` if you set `units="in"`:

```
png("testplot.png", width=3, height=4, units="in", pointsize=12, res=300)
plot(1:10, rnorm(10, 0, 5))
dev.off()
```

with another size:

```
png("testplot2.png", width=3, height=3, units="in", pointsize=12, res=300)
plot(1:10, rnorm(10, 0, 5))
dev.off()
```

[image]
[image]